# Highslide ajax using form with submit

Tags: php, highslide

I'm using a form with Highslide and ajax calling a file editphotos.php like this

```
<a href=\"editphotos.php?id=$imageid_\" onclick=\"return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'ajax'} )\" title='edit picture: $filename_'>.
```

Now what I would like to achieve is that after I click on a update or delete button in the form I would like it to load url like:

```
index.php?id=1&deleted=1&refresh=1
```

Now it simply closes the highslide ajax window.
Is there a way to do this?

Regards,
Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t open a second url inside a Highslide ajax popup. You need to use `objectType: 'iframe'` if you want to do that.

Comment: Hi RoadRash,thank you. Yes I noticed this and I got the updates and deleting pictures workign using iframe. Is there a way to automaically close the iframe after a form has been submitted?

Comment: Using this on the form loads the page.. onsubmit=\"setTimeout(function(){parent.location.reload(true);},100)\" only problem is that the page loads for some reason very slowly..

Comment: Please see this Highslide FAQ item: http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3768

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t see your second comment before I posted mine. I think it’s safer to submit the form to a confirmation page, and then run the close script from the FAQ in the confirmation page. Or the reload script if you want. Highslide can’t do anything about the loading time of the parent page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I will try this out. this case is solved :)