# Highslide Autoclose iframe popup

Tags: highslide

this a related question to this [question 14591396](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591396/highslide-ajax-using-form-with-submit)
Can I autoclose the iframe popup after a submit has been pressed in 3 seconds?

Regards, Toby

Comment: Almost got it working this way: only problem is that this script closes the iframe immediatly after hitting submit button: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function alertFunction()
{
 var answer = confirm("Delete picture?")
  function closeMe() {
       try {
          parent.window.hs.close();
       } catch (e) {}
   }
   setTimeout('closeMe()', 2000); 
 if (answer){

 return closeMe();
 }
 else{
  return false;
 }
 document.getElementById("delphoto").innerHTML=x;

}
</script>

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, see http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3768.

The only difference would be that you start the timeout when the user submits the form.

```
myForm.onsubmit = function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
      try {
         parent.window.hs.getExpander().close();
      } catch (e) {}
   }, 3000);
});
```